# how to fetch random stores name but price in ascending order from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

> how to use fetch 'food_store' order by randomly and price order by ASC ? 
>   write now i am using this query

```
Select * from `food` where `veg_non` = 'Veg' and `food_price` <= ? ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: doesn't sound terribly random unless you describe the problem better

Comment: Select * from FOOD where food_store ORDER BY RAND() and food_price <= ? ORDER BY food_price .. this i want query is not working i just made it to explain it :p sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select *, RAND() as r from `food` where `veg_non` = 'Veg'
    and `food_price` <= ? ORDER BY `food_price` ASC, r ASC
```

Comment: what is this 'r' ?? but it's giving me some extra info like ,"r":0.58398468846826

Comment: r is just a name for the random number that has been added as a column in the query result, it can be called anything you want. You can just ignore it in the output, it's just there so you can generate the random order.